C 'String Array' Function Returns Empty
I'm writing this program to enumerate every file in the directory to practice using pointers because I am new to the concept and the C language. The return statement to **getFiles() comes back empty for some reason. Weirdly, in the getFiles() function, when I print my 'array of strings' (dirs), it prints 1 of the 3 files I have in my directory. However, when I print the results in main(), nothing happens.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char **getFiles();
    printf("\nFUNCTION RETURN:\n%s", *getFiles());
    return 0;
}
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

char **getFiles(){

    char **dirs;

    int total = 10; //Need to do this
    dirs = malloc(total*sizeof(char *));

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    struct dirent *de;  
  
    DIR *dr = opendir("."); 
  
    if (dr == NULL)  
    { 
        printf("Error"); 
        return 0; 
    } 
  
    int x=0;
    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){ 
            int length = strlen(de->d_name);
            dirs[x] = malloc(length*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(buffer, de->d_name);
            strcpy(dirs[x], buffer);
            dirs[x] = buffer;
            x++;
    }

    closedir(dr);     
    printf("\nPRINT DIRS\n:\n%s", *dirs);
    return dirs;
    for(int i =0; i<x;i++){
        free(dirs[i]);
    }
    free(dirs);
}

As I said I'm still new to this whole pointers and addresses thing so I tried de-referencing a bunch of stuff and printing that but nothing really helped.

The code after return dirs; will never execute. dirs[x] = buffer; is assigning a pointer to a local variable to dirs[x]. Once the function returns that local variable is destroyed leaving a dangling pointer to an invalid memory address. That is undefined behavior. There are a few other things wrong here too, like not allocating enough space for the terminating 0 and the weird strcpy dance. and no check to make sure x is never greater than 9.

If you get things wrong like expecting codes to run after return dirs;, you probably are not ready to learn about pointers yet. Get the basics right before going deeper. Also I hope you understand what the statement char **getFiles(); in main does. In particular, it does not execute anything.

You're storing pointers to buffer in your dirs array.  But buffer is local to getFiles, so is no longer valid after getFiles returns.  That's undefined behavior.  And as mentioned, the code after your return statement obviously can never be reached, so it's dead code that serves no purpose.  Move it someplace else.

OT: Please refer to either 'program' or 'code' or, perhaps, 'function'. In the vernacular. 'script' has a meaning that is not applicable to C source code. Just FYI... :-)

Another answer, hopefully more complete.
If you are going to read a directory’s list of names, do it all at once. The directory content can change at any time, even when you are reading its contents! So the more quickly you can get through it, the more likely the listing you get is correct.
You can monitor a directory for changes to be sure you got it right, but that is a subject I will only mention in passing here. Here’s a quickly-Googled link to start learning more: What is the proper way to use inotify?
Get the Directory Contents
To collect just a list of names relative to a given directory (using your code template):
// getFileNames()
// freeFileNames()
// countFileNames()

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

char **getFileNames(const char *dirname){

    // Our final result will be a dynamically-allocated list
    // of dynamically-allocated filenames (relative to dirname).
    // The list ends with a NULL filename.
    char **filenames = NULL;

    // We wish to make a single pass through the directory, so we
    // will use a linked list to collect filenames AND count them.
    struct node {char *filename; struct node *next;};
    struct node * head = NULL;
    size_t count = 0;

    // Scan through the directory,
    // pushing each new filename to the head of the list
    DIR *dir = opendir(dirname);
    if (!dir) return NULL;

    struct dirent *de;
    while ((de = readdir(dir))){
        struct node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (!node) goto lerror;
        node->filename = strdup(de->d_name);
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
        count += 1;
    }
    closedir(dir);

    // Now allocate the resulting array
    // and move all the collected filenames to it,
    // dismantling the linked list as we go
    filenames = malloc((count+1) * sizeof(char*));
    if (!filenames) goto lerror;
    filenames[count] = NULL;

    while (head){
        struct node *next = head->next;
        filenames[--count] = head->filename;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
    return filenames;

lerror:
    // If something went wrong, we'll need to clean up
    while (head){
        struct node *next = head->next;
        free(head->filename);
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char **freeFileNames(char **filenames){
    // Free each filename
    for (size_t n = 0;  filenames[n];  n++)
        free(filenames[n]);
    // And free the list
    free(filenames);
    return NULL;
}

size_t countFileNames(char **filenames){
    size_t count = 0;
    while (filenames[count])
        count += 1;
    return count;
}

Notice that I changed the function to take as argument the path (relative or absolute) to the directory you wish to examine. This is a good practice! Let the caller determine which directory we want to read without having to dink with first changing the CWD and then restoring it afterwards.
Because the function does not return the number of files in the list, the list itself is terminated with a NULL string. This is a common design in C when dealing with lists of this type.
⟶ For example, main()’s argc is not really anything more than a convenience, because argv ends with a NULL string! That is to say, argv[argc] == NULL!
And once again, it is important to note that the returned list of filenames is relative to the argument directory. You could return the full path of each file (== absolute path name). This would require help concatenating the directory name and filename before strdup()ing it into the resulting list.
Or you could leave it as-is and simply compose the full file path whenever you needed it later. It’s easy enough to write a little function to do that:
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <string.h>

char *JoinDirAndFileName(const char *dirname, const char *filename){
    char path[PATH_MAX] = "";
    strcpy(path, dirname);
    strcat(path, "/");
    strcat(path, filename);
    return strdup(path);
}

This, of course, requires the dirname argument to be a full path name itself, lol.
Is It A Directory?
Additional useful information can be obtained about the files using the stat() family of functions. For example, we might like to know whether a filename refers to a directory or not:
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool isDirectory(const char *filename){
    struct stat sb;
    if (stat( filename, &sb )) return false;  // Failure == not a directory
    return (sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR;
}

Keep in mind that this requires either:

filename is an absolute path name for the file (which in our case it is not), or
filename is relative, meaning the file is in the current working directory (which in our case it is)

Sort the Filenames
You may wish to use that information to do things like sort the filenames.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int FileNameCompare(const void *a, const void *b){
    // Sort directory names before filenames
    // Then sort using strcmp()
    bool is_dir_a = isDirectory(*(const char **)a);
    bool is_dir_b = isDirectory(*(const char **)b);
    if (is_dir_a == is_dir_b) 
        return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
    return is_dir_a ? -1 : 1;
}

void SortFileNames(char **filenames){
    qsort(filenames, countFileNames(filenames), sizeof(char *), FileNameCompare);
}

Again, the sort only works if isDirectory() gets a filename it can use stat() on, meaning either

the list of filenames is a list of absolute file paths, or
the filenames in the list are relative to the CWD.
For our example program the latter is true.

An Example Program
Now we can put it all together as an example program:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    // Get the list of filenames in the CWD
    char **filenames = getFileNames(".");
    if (!filenames)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", "fooey!" );
        return 1;
    }

    // Might as well sort them
    SortFileNames(filenames);

    // Print the list
    puts("FILENAMES:");
    for (size_t n = 0;  filenames[n];  n++)
        if (isDirectory(filenames[n]))
            printf("  %s/\n", filenames[n]);
        else
            printf("  %s\n", filenames[n]);

    // Clean up
    filenames = freeFileNames(filenames);
    return 0;
}

To compile and run the example program, just concatenate all the code blocks into a text file and save it as dirlist.c, then compile it with something like:
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -O3 dirlist.c -o dirlist
$ ./dirlist
FILENAMES:
  ./
  ../
  dirlist
  dirlist.c
$

Windows ≠ Linux
Alas, Windows users, getting a directory’s content requires different functions, but it all works very much the same way. You can read more starting with some convenient Microsoft documentation: FindFirstFile(), FindNextFile(), FindClose(), and other File Management Functions.

Nice code. Small niggle... Every comparison made by qsort() will perform 2 system calls to separate directories from ordinary files. Then, another system call for each entry when printing... Seems suboptimal when membership in one of two species could be determined and memo'd at the time of scanning... Just a thought... Cheers!

@Fe2O3 Yes, it’s decidedly sub-optimal in that regard. (I actually had it in my mind that it was worse than that, lol.) I’d personally keep more information about each entry than just the name, but I figured this was good enough to deal with just iterating over the directory. Good to see you!

@Fe2O3 On Linux, those system calls might be avoided with data from the d_type field of the dirent structure, assuming the underlying filesystem supports the d_type field.

@AndrewHenle The manual is clear that even if d_type exists in the structure, it may not have useful info depending on the user’s filesystem. It is absolutely worth the time to check and use it if available, but I am disinclined to make this answer be anything more than a direct response to the Q asked, including not changing data response to something other than the OP’s char * array[] structure. I haven’t looked to see if there’s another SO read-a-directory Q that directly asks “how to read a directory”, but suggestions for action on that point are welcome.

@Dúthomhas Hi back!  I bring up my niggle because (imo) determination of flavour of entry while scanning would be half way to the elaboration (OP's task, not yours!) of adding in recursive descent of directory structure... Yours is a VG answer to OP's problem (UV'd)... Just mentioning something for OP to think about... Cheers! :-)

This is what I ended up going with mostly based off the concise answer from wtf i'm reading and additional research I did with the information he gave me. Thanks for your time and your answers :)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

char** list_files(const char *path, int *count) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dp = opendir(path);

    if (dp == NULL) {
        perror("opendir");
        return NULL;
    }

    *count = 0;
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        (*count)++;
    }
    rewinddir(dp);

    char **files = malloc((*count) * sizeof(char*));
    if (files == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        closedir(dp);
        return NULL;
    }

    int index = 0;
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        files[index] = strdup(entry->d_name);
        if (files[index] == NULL) {
            perror("strdup");
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                free(files[i]);
            }
            free(files);
            closedir(dp);
            return NULL;
        }
        index++;
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return files;
}

As requested I will provide more of my thought process and explanations to my solution:
To start, I removed the int main() function to put this function in a library because I realised I was probably going to need something like this for a future project. I then added the parameters for path (stored in a 'string') and the pointer to an int count. I used a pointer here because I still need to access this integer in the script using this library. The pointer allows us to modify the value of the variable at it's memory address (which we will need to free memory in the script using the library). In the if statement if (dp == NULL), I changed printf("Error"); to use perror() mainly because you cannot have printf(""); in a library. You can read more about this here. I also changed strcpy(buffer, de->d_name); to files[index] = strdup(entry->d_name);, as strdup() allocates memory for the new string on the heap, allowing us to use it in a different function.
Honorable mention to @Dúthomhas for going into extensive detail on my question despite me already having answered it.

You should emphasize where you are allocating pointers and where you are allocating storage for the strings. Helping the user understand that allocating for a type** variable is a two-step process, allocating storage for the pointers and then allocating storage for each string assigning the starting address for the allocated block holding the string to the next unused pointer in the allocated block of pointers.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

What happens when another process adds a few entries AFTER this function has counted the old quantity, but BEFORE this function fills its array? Buffer overrun... This answer, as it is, is not robust...

Thinking a bit longer... If another process REMOVES entries during the critical interval, this function will return the wrong count via *count and leave garbage pointers (because of malloc(), not calloc()) that the caller will use... Program crashes...

@Fe2O3 Hey! Thanks for your feedback. I was just wondering how you would even test something like this effectively.

@JacobThevenot Come back tomorrow. I'm brooding on making a post to SO triggered by this Q&A... (Will make every effort to avoid "toxic" ambiance... No need to go out and buy iodine & bandaids...) If posted, it should show-up in the right sidebar here under "Linked questions"... Now, for me to get to work on it... Cheers!... Very crude work around for now: use calloc() to account for fewer entries than counted (caller takes responsibility) and use while ( index < *count && (entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) to account for more entries than counted 3ms ago...

First :
char **getFiles();

That is incorrect.
Where is the name of the variable?
char **my_files = getFiles();

Here the good way to do it.
int length = strlen(de->d_name);
dirs[x] = malloc(length*sizeof(char));
strcpy(buffer, de->d_name);
strcpy(dirs[x], buffer);
dirs[x] = buffer;

Why not just use strdup() ?
return dirs;
for(int i =0; i<x;i++){
    free(dirs[i]);
}
free(dirs);

All code after a return not gonna be execute.
Here something to help you :
GNU C Language Introduction and Reference Manual
And here something... (hoping you don't use it, if you don't understand it):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TOTAL_DIR 10

char **
getFiles(void)
{
    char             **dirs;
    struct dirent    *de;
    DIR              *dr;

    dr = opendir(".");
    if (dr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return (0);
    }

    dirs = calloc(TOTAL_DIR, sizeof(char *));
    if (dirs == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return (0);
    }

    int x = 0;
    de = readdir(dr);
    while (de != NULL)
    {
        dirs[x] = strdup(de->d_name);
        x++;
        de = readdir(dr);
    }
    closedir(dr);
    return (dirs);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char **files;

    files = getFiles();
    printf("Files : \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_DIR; i++)
    {
        if (files[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", files[i]);
        free(files[i]);
    }
    free(files);
    return (0);
}



The OP misplaced a forward function declaration inside main(). It's not wrong, but it's not conventional. 2) Your program will misbehave if the directory being read contains >10 entries... program accesses memory beyond dirs[ 9 ]... UB awaits... Major niggle: return (0); should be return NULL;... Minor niggle: return is not a function. Inappropriate parentheses are unconventional.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
